# Detect scanned document orientation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, fft, tesseract

Is there any way to detect scanned document orientation in flutter, There are examples in python
[Detect image orientation angle based on text direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010660/detect-image-orientation-angle-based-on-text-direction)
and [How to detect image orientation (text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559525/how-to-detect-image-orientation-text)
but is there any way to achieve this in flutter.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a **Appwrite** function or other service which can use the the same python code and return the orientation to your flutter app.
check the docs: https://appwrite.io/docs/functions

Comment: Actually, this has to be done on device itself